# CASE is behaving different in Debug and normal mode

Tags: bash, shell

I have wrote a script in which the "CASE" portion identify whether the byte/char entered is Lower, Upper , digit or some special character. The program runs fine but the odd thing is; When i enter the alphabet "A", and run

```
sh -x ./scrip "A"
```

Output

```
+ [ 1 -ne 1 ]
+ char=A
+ wc -c
+ echo A
+ NumOfChars=2
+ [ 2 -gt 2 ]
+ echo  Arguments are correct in numbers 
 Arguments are correct in numbers 
+ echo Upper case alphabet
Upper case alphabet
```

The output is correct (i.e. the case [A-Z] is executed

But when i execute the program is normal fashion i.e.

```
./script "A"
```

Output

```
Lower case alphabet
```

The CASE [a-z] is executed instead, why ?

The script is as follows

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Number of arguments are wrong"
    exit 1;

else
    char="$1"
    NumOfChars=$(echo "$char" | wc -c)
    if [ "$NumOfChars" -gt 2 ]; then
        echo "Number of characters are greater then one"
        exit 2;
    else
        echo " Arguments are correct in numbers ";
    fi
fi
case "$char"
in

[a-z] ) echo "Lower case alphabet";;
[A-Z] ) echo "Upper case alphabet";;
[0-9] ) echo "Digit";;
* )     echo "Non AlphaNumeric characters/byte";;
esac
```

Comment: The script outputs `Lower case alphabet` in both cases. Maybe you are actually calling different script, or is it just a typo in this post: `sh -x ./scrip "A"` ? (Did you mean `sh -x ./script "A"`?)

Comment: Prepend `LC_ALL=C` in both cases: `LC_ALL=C ./script "A"`, and `sh -x ./scrip "A"` to get rid of the `locale` issue.

Comment: Also, without a shebang line, it's unclear in what shell the script is running when called without `sh`, and the same is unclear with `sh`, as it could be `bash`, `dash`, or whatever else depending on your distribution's taste.

Comment: and since this is all about case-sensitivity: the statement is called `case` not `CASE`. (how's the shell supposed to differentiate between upper and lower case letters, if you cannot?)

Comment: Thank you all for you helpful replies. I have added ( #!/bin/sh ) and it worked.
Now the script will be executed by only /bin/sh but what is the meaning of this environmental variable ? I means "LC_COLLATE" and by assigning "C" what's the difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you are bitten by two different problems:

- because of the missing shebang your script will/can be executed by *different* shell implementations when run with `sh ./script.sh` resp. `./script.sh`
- the `bash` (which happens to execute the script when run as `./script.sh`) can match `A` into the `[a-z]` for specific locales.

the fix is to specify both a shebang and the collate sequence:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LC_COLLATE="C"

# the rest of the script is unchanged.
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Number of arguments are wrong"
    exit 1;

else
    char="$1"
    NumOfChars=$(echo "$char" | wc -c)
    if [ "$NumOfChars" -gt 2 ]; then
        echo "Number of characters are greater then one"
        exit 2;
    else
        echo " Arguments are correct in numbers ";
    fi
fi
case "$char"
in

[a-z] ) echo "Lower case alphabet";;
[A-Z] ) echo "Upper case alphabet";;
[0-9] ) echo "Digit";;
* )     echo "Non AlphaNumeric characters/byte";;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But i doens't get the meaning of LC_COLLATE="C". What's its purpose here ?

Comment: @NoumanTajik the [so] way of saying "thank you" is to *upvote*. if a post answers your question, you should (also) *accept* it.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE` sets the collation order (how characters are sorted, considered equal, ... within a given `locale`). `C` is the [`POSIX locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmbx.html#glmar), which does collation "for computers rather than humans"

Comment: I have tried the "up-vote" but the stack overflow says " Thank you for the feedback, vote cast by those with less then 15 reputation are recorded but don't change the publicly display score".
I have recently joined stack overflow maybe they don't consider the up-vote of noobs :)